# Infinitely many $n$ which divide $3^{6n-1} - 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, exponentiation, perfect-powers

Are there infinitely many positive integers $n$ such that $n$ divides $3^{6n-1} - 1$?

I guess the answer should be positive and the only reasonable idea I have is to consider $n = 3^k - 1$ since if $k$ divides $6 \cdot 3^k - 7$ we will be done - but I do not know if this can be used nicely.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you, say, found some $n$ for which this holds?

Comment: What is the source of this problem?  Is there any reason to imagine that it has a sensible answer?

Comment: @lulu The point is that it is tightly related to "are there infinitely many $k$ which divide $3^k-3$ but not $2^k-2?".

Comment: That's really not a lot of context.  I have found $5$ examples.  I assume you have searched as well.  What examples have you found?

Comment: The first 10 $n$ are $1,2,11,46,121,1441,5786,7702,60766,175571$. OEIS does not know about this sequence.

Comment: It seems both $3^{6\cdot 11 -1} - 1$ and  $6 \cdot 3^{11} - 7$ are divisible by $11$

Comment: It's relatively easy to generate larger and larger examples by adding suitable prime factors to already known examples, e.g. $n_0=1441$,$n_1=14821\cdot n_0$,$n_2=17291\cdot n_1$, $n_3=59281\cdot n_2$,$n_4=61751\cdot n_3$,$n_5=7293911\cdot n_4$ all work ... (it's not a proof of anything though)

Comment: $$\mathrm{ord}_n(3)\mid 6n-1$$

Comment: Let $m$ is the factor of Euler's Totient Function $\phi(n)$ and smallest number such that $3^m\equiv 1 \pmod n$ and $6n-1\equiv 0 \pmod m$, then
$3^{6n-1}\equiv 1 \pmod n$.

There are more $n$;$177146,182531,205801,702526.$

Comment: In fact the only primes that can work are $2,11$ by $6n-1=6(n-1)+(6-1)$

Comment: The largest solution I found so far is $$5\ 333\ 286\ 541$$